# How to limit the number of fetched items by a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

The 'posts_per_page' is not limiting the number of items WP_Query will fetch.
Which is OK, however I need to find a way how to break the WP_Query with some limit or break like attribute after 3 items are fetched. I have many items and to fetch 3 items it get all the 1000+ items in my database, which is slowing down the page in the end.

Any idea how to limit the query to get only 3 instead of all items from the db?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'books' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'book_state',
            'value' => 'sold'
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 

    $booksNumber  = $the_query->found_posts; // returns 1282 instead of 3

    ...
```

Comment: Without looking at the WordPress source, I am pretty sure that you are not fetching all posts but just the total count so that you can use that for for example pagination or to display the total number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`found_posts` returns the total number of posts matching the query parameters.

`post_count` returns the total number of posts being displayed.  I *believe* what you want to do is:

```
$booksNumber  = $the_query->post_count;
```

If that doesn't work, I would try using [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) instead of `WP_Query`:

```
$postslist = get_posts($args);
$booksNumber = count($postslist);
```

Comment: Nice. `post_count` is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're only using one meta query, so try using **[get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)**.

Normally, I'd recommend WP_Query, but I can see how it can be confusing. If you run the following code you will see something more like what you're expecting:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'books',
    'meta_key' => 'book_state',
    'meta_value' => 'sold',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
echo count($posts);
var_dump($posts);
```